# curl content of web page

Tags: php, curl, web

What is the problem with the following code?

```
<?php
    function file_get_contents_curl($url) 
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $data;
    }

    $var = file_get_contents_curl("http://www.sahibinden.com/131521670");
    var_dump($var);      

?>
```

It just display bool(false)

URL could be problem when put http://www.sahibinden.com/131521670 on browsers address bar, browser redirected to another page that I want its content.

when I add following lines

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp );
```

output was

```
* About to connect() to www.sahibinden.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 195.33.232.72... * connected
* Connected to www.sahibinden.com (195.33.232.72) port 80 (#0)
> GET /131521670 HTTP/1.1

Host: www.sahibinden.com

Accept: */*

* Closing connection #0
* Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  also produce same result.

Comment: Use `curl_error()` to see any errors you are probably getting

Comment: Add `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` ...

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143138/curl-not-following-the-location-header